# Apex Task Trigger cannot handle batch operations on recurring tasks error

Tags: apex, trigger

I have to delete all the tasks (both single and recurring) when a case is cancelled. I have tried a trigger which is showing the error that the Apex task trigger can't handle recurring tasks. What would be a possible workaround ?

Below is what I have tried.

```
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Case> newCases){
     set<id> caseIdSet = new set<id>();
    list<task> toUpdateTaskLst = new list<task> ();
     for(case c : newcases)
    {
        caseIdSet.add(c.id);   
        system.debug('caseIdSet  '+caseIdSet);
    }
    for(case c: [select Id , (select id, whatid, status from tasks) from Case where id in :caseIdSet and status = 'cancelled' ] )
    {
        if(!c.tasks.isEmpty() && c.tasks != null )
        {
            for(task t: c.tasks)
            {
                system.debug('t.status'+t.status);
                t.status = 'Completed';
                toUpdateTaskLst.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
    update toUpdateTaskLst;

 }
```

Comment: frame your question properly... cancelled is cancelled means??

Comment: did you try this: http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/08/close-recurring-tasks-using-apex.html

Comment: You can also right Apex Batch that will run daily and delete the task of the cancelled cases.

Comment: @Sandhya - if either of the below answers helped you please mark one as your preferred answer to encourage others helping out in the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

**Trigger to pass Task** `Id` **of related Cases that are on** `Status='Cancelled'`:

```
trigger DeleteCaseTaskOnCancelledStatus on Case (after insert, after update) {

  Set<Id> listTaskToDelete = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> listCases = new Set<Id>(); 

  for(List<Case> cases : [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Status='Cancelled' AND Id IN: trigger.new])
  {
   if(!cases.isEmpty() && cases.size()>0)
  {
   for(Case c: cases)
    {
      listCases.add(c.Id);
    }

  }
}

for(List<Task> taskList : [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN: listCases])
{
    if(!taskList.isEmpty() && taskList.size()>0)
    {
      for(Task t: taskList)
      {
        listTaskToDelete.add(t.Id); 
      }
    }
}

if(!listTaskToDelete.isEmpty() && listTaskToDelete.size()>0)

    TaskFutureDeletionClass.sendToDelete(listTaskToDelete); 


}
```

**Then you pass their ids to a class with a** `@future` **method, like this:**

```
global class TaskFutureDeletionClass{

  @future
  public static void sendToDelete(Set<Id> tasksList)
  {   

   List<Task> tasksToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE Id IN: tasksList]; 

    try{
        delete tasksToDelete;   

        }catch(Exception e)
         {
          for(Task t: tasksToDelete)
          {
           t.addError('There was a problem deleting this task ' + e);
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Salesforce will take care of deletion when resources are available.

**UPDATE:**

Added the `WhatId` and changed the name of the trigger to point the **Case** object rather than the **Task** object.

**UPDATE:** (*One trigger to handle all trigger context variables*)

I think it would be better to have a trigger that handles all trigger contexts variables for Case.

```
trigger DeleteCaseTaskOnCancelledStatus on Case (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete)
{


    if((trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) || (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate))
    {
      DeletionProcessForCancelledCases.startDeletionProcess();
    }

}
```

**Then we call our helper class:**

```
 public with sharing class DeletionProcessForCancelledCases {

  public static void startDeletionProcess()
  {
   Set<Id> listTaskToDelete = new Set<Id>();
   Set<Id> listCases = new Set<Id>(); 


    for(Case c:(List<Case>) trigger.new)
    {
        if(c.Status =='Cancelled')
         listCases.add(c.Id);
    }


for(List<Task> taskList : [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN: listCases])
{
  if(!taskList.isEmpty() && taskList.size()>0)
  {
   for(Task t: taskList)
   {
     listTaskToDelete.add(t.Id); 
   }
  } 
}  

 if(!listTaskToDelete.isEmpty() && listTaskToDelete.size()>0)

    TaskFutureDeletionClass.sendToDelete(listTaskToDelete); 
 }
}
```

Then our `TaskFutureDeletionClass.sendToDelete(listTaskToDelete);` is executed and the `@future` method will take care of the rest of the operation.

Comment: Hi Carlos, The trigger should be on Case object and I need to delete the tasks when case status is cancelled.

Comment: You can try the new with a new trigger. Actually, it will be also better to move the logic out of the trigger to a helper class.

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says. You'll need to process these asynchronously. Consider using [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm) or [future methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm). You'll need to set up a class to handle any processing you need.

```
Task[] syncTasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND IsRecurring = FALSE AND WhatId = (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Status = 'Cancelled'];
Task[] asyncTasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND IsRecurring = TRUE AND WhatId = (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Status = 'Cancelled'];
delete syncTasks;
if(asyncTasks.size() > 0) {
  CaseTriggerHelper.completeTasksAsync(asyncTasks);
}
```

CaseTriggerHelper.completeTasksAsync could lead to a future method, or a queueable that can process the tasks, or a batchable class, whichever way you'd like to process those tasks.